# HTML accessibility combobox role

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility, wai-aria

I have the following layout in my project:

```
<div class="css-c18mwd-ImageFrameBase-ImageFrameWithGradient-SecondaryImageFrameWithGradient e1jjxv8j4">
<button tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" class="css-11ubmv-MediaGridButton e1jjxv8j1">Enlarge Nordic Blue Nokia X20 from Front and Back</button>
</div>
```

But when I review the accessibility tab, it says that the role for my `button` is `combobox` as shown in the screenshot below.

How can I change it to be more accessible and have a role of `button` like the other buttons on the page?

[image: Accesiblity Tree]

Comment: It has `aria-haspopup="true"`. That sounds like a combobox to me. What makes it not a combobox and, if it isn't a combobox, why does it have a popup? (You can use `role="button"` but you should resolve the conflict so it works properly with accessibility devices.)

Comment: @Ouroborus Hi thank you very much for your answer, I'm trying to make it accessible. it functionality is when clicking on button I open modal that displays image, would be ok if I remove aria-haspopup ?

Comment: @Loki this is exactly what a combobox is `The combobox role identifies an element as an input that controls another element, such as a listbox or grid, that can dynamically pop up to help the user set the value of that input.` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/combobox_role

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Thank you for your response , but I have a request by the user ... that button 
still do not have a programmatically defined button role, what would that mean?

Comment: `aria-haspopup="true"` sets button's role implicitly to `combobox`.  `I have a request by the user` what request?

Comment: that button is missing programmatically defined button role

Comment: You'll need to ask your user for details. It should be `role="combobox"` which is already implied. (`role="button"` if you really do need it to be button, but this is likely wrong. Your user may have misspoken, may be misinformed, or may be just wrong.) But I wonder if it's because you aren't setting [`aria-expanded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-expanded) when the popup opens and closes.

Comment: Click on a button to open a popup in another component (popup that shows image in HD), that's why I thought maybe it should be regular button. Should aria-expanded be on a button or on a popup component?

Comment: If the button opens a dialog, it should have `aria-haspopu="dialog"`. The will probably change the role back to button, as it should. This seems appropriate based on the button text in your screenshot.

Comment: Can you please share more code? What role does the opened popup have?

Comment: `aria-expanded` should be on the button. How to use it is described in the doc I had linked..

Comment: Did you test it? It seems Chrome doesn’t care, it still exposes `combobox` with `aria-expanded` present, and with `aria-haspopup="dialog"` as well. Firefox makes a difference. In my opinion the case here is closer to a dialog than a combobox or a menu. And while we can set `aria-haspopup="dialog"` on the button, I haven’t seen a modal dialog with either attribute yet. Even the [APG Dialog Pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/dialogmodal/) doesn’t use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s a curious case. I believe you should remove `aria-haspopup` (and `tabindex` while you’re at it, that’s redundant for `<button>`).

Just as a reminder before we continue: What counts is what screen readers announce in the end, and to be compliant with the relevant standards.

From [the `haspopup` attribute documentation](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#aria-haspopup):

> A popup element usually appears as a block of content that is on top of other content. Authors MUST ensure that the role of the element that serves as the container for the popup content is `menu, listbox, tree, grid`, or `dialog`, and that the value of `aria-haspopup` matches the role of the popup container.

If I understand correctly from your comments you are opening a larger view of an image. From the list above, the only fitting role would be that of `dialog`.

When looking at the [documentation for the `dialog` role](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#dialog), you will not find any mention of `haspopup`, nor have I seen any dialog pattern with that attribute.

Even the [Modal Dialog Example on the ARIA Authoring Practices Guide](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/example-index/dialog-modal/dialog.html#sc1) does not make use of that attribute. Neither does the [Bootstrap Modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/#live-demo).

**So my suggestion is to follow these guides and simply remove `aria-hasdialog` and make sure your dialog is implementing all requirements right.**

Further, I believe that browsers are not meant to change the element’s role dependent on the value in that attribute. I’m even more reassured by the fact that [`aria-hasdialog` is deprecated except for chosen roles, and `button` is among them](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#h-note-51). How would that make sense if it changed that role?

### Test results

Chrome exposes the `combobox` role in all these cases:

```
<button aria-haspopup="true">Enlarge Image</button>
<button aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Enlarge Image</button>
<button aria-haspopup="dialog">Enlarge Image</button>
```

NVDA with Firefox and Chrome will announce:

> Enlarge image, Menu button, submenu
> Enlarge image, Menu button, collapsed, submenu
> Enlarge image, Menu* button, submenu

- only announced with Chrome

Chromvox will announce:

> Enlarge image, popup button
> Enlarge image, popup button collapsed
> Enlarge image, button, submenu

If anybody could test with Jaws that would be great.

The fact that browsers change the button’s role when `haspopup` is present seems weird, but might be due to the fact that no button opening a dialog uses that attribute in the wild.